# Catalog Price rule, Attribute condition=does not contain, is not applying if no value selected from dropdown list

Tags: magento2

In magento2 admin, Catalog Price rule, Attribute condition="does not contain", is not applying if **NO** value selected from drop down list

[image]

[image]

Here condition is not applied. [image]

For other products if at least one value is selected in Ranges, only than the rule apply.